# Facebook ads deactivating button won't work

Tags: facebook

Facebook is charging me money on a daily basis without any kind of authorization.

I want to close FB Ads account and it's been so hard. I finally found the button and it doesn't seem to work on any browser. After I click nothing happens!

[image]

Do you think is a software bug? Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You should contact facebook support about this. They can probably make the change on the server side for you. Also try unchecking all and press save changes. If that doesn't work, report that to facebook support as well.

Comment: Please help me man! I don't have FB personal account, just business account so I can't publish on FB foruns. I've read people that needed to cancel their credit card because of this!
And now it simply wont work! https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/settings.php?act=357755294301278

Comment: I contaced now my bank, and it is not possible to forbid FB from charging my credit card account! I need your help guys, FB is really a monster sucking money from clients

Comment: Have you unchecked all options as written in my solution, and saved that? It is important to know if that works or not.

Comment: Yes, I uncheckd all options! Still doesn't work!

Comment: Can you try a different browser?

Comment: It seems there is a problem with Firefox. With IE it worked!

Comment: There you go! Could be a plugin, or just clearing your cache, or just a bug in facebook's code for firefox compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox didn't work. I tried with Internet Explorer and it worked!